# How to insert a pipe and command into the end of the current input?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I found a nice command called espeak.
It can read from stdin and speak up its result.

```
$ du -sh . | espeak
$ ls -a | grep foobar | espeak
etc
```

Anyway, it works fine but I think that putting `| espeak` into the end of a line every time isn't efficient.
So I want to insert it automatically without typing by hand.
Is there good way to achieve this?

Comment: On second thought there is a way after all. Redirect stdout (and stderr if you'd like to) globally to a file, then fire off `espeak` from a debug trap.

Comment: Tag bash **or** zsh, not both; they're different shells, with different syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you also want to see the output, you could do this:

```
exec > >(tee >(espeak))
```

That redirects `stdout` to a `tee` process which sends everything to an `espeak` process, as well as sending it on to the console or whatever `stdout` was sending to before. (For those following along at home, `stdout` for the `tee` process hasn't yet been redirected when it starts up, so it is still the same as it was before the `exec` command.)

Have fun.

To turn it off:

```
exec > /dev/tty
```

Comment: Ah, Using exec looks like the most efficient and simple way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In zsh there is a widget `accept-line` that is triggered when the input line is accepted. You can override the default widget with you own, like this :

```
function accept-line
{
    #here, add espeak to the current command
    BUFFER=$BUFFER" | espeak"

    # to be clear, if the input string was 'ls -l',
    # now it is 'ls -l | espeak', and this is the command that will be executed

    # trigger the real widget to accept the line and run the input buffer
    zle .accept-line
}
# register your new accept-line widget to replace the builtin one
zle -N accept-line
```

Here I used the name `accept-line` but if you want to name your override function `my_superOverride` you can override the default widget at the end with :

```
zle -N accept-line my_superOverride
```

---

The only drawback is that for commands like `do something ; do something else` it will speak only the output of `do something else`..